# Quick android layout questions

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Say if I had a layout, "X", with one button: "x". When I click "x", it opens up "Y", and there is a "y" button. What I am aiming to achieve is: When "y" is clicked, it changes the button "x" text and image to something else. But, what is happening instead is that it is opening up a new, identical layout to "X", with the same button "x", and applying the changes in that layout.

Some paint attempts for better visual understanding:

http://tinypic.com/r/2417ev7/8

But this is what actually happens:

http://tinypic.com/r/1p9q2b/8

Comment: What is Y here ??? a layout in another Activity or in same activity as X.

Comment: @twntee Y is in another Activity

Comment: So you are going from Activity X, to Activity Y, back to Activity X with modified layout text? I would startActivityForResult() for Activity Y and then as the result, reset my text in Activity X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am getting you have an **Activity A** with a layout **X** with a button **x** in it, and another **Activity B** with a layout **Y** and button **y** in it.

Now on clicking button **x** you start the activity **B**, which shows the **Y** layout, and now on clicking the button **y** you want to close this activity **B** and change the text of button **x**.

There are possibly two ways to do this

1. **`startActivityForResult()`** : this way you start Activity **Y** on click of button **X**, which on press of button **y** returns a result and finishes itself, now when result is received you can change the text of button **x** in the `onActivityResult()` method.
2. **Using `Intents`** : this is fairly simple, what you do is on click of button x you finish your activity **A** and start Activity **B**, and on click of button **y** you finish activity **B** and start activity **A**, passing a string value in the intent for the text to be set for button **x**, and then receive this `intent` in `onCreate()` of activity **A** and simply change the text of button **x**.

Comment: Could you briefly explain how to use startActivityForResult() if I wanted to change button "x" into the drawable "picture"?

Comment: @Piofmc as written above, on click of button x startActivityForResult(Activity Y) >>> and then on click of button y setResult(Some intent...), finish your Y activity >>> and then in onActivityResult(), change the button x background image, (Please note it has to be an Imagebutton if you are into changing backgrounds)